# How should platformer game's solid objects be implemented efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, implementation

I have been trying to write a platformer engine for a few times now. The thing is I am not quite satisfied with my implementation details on solid objects. (wall, floor, ceiling) I have several scenario I would like to discuss.

For a simple platformer game like the first Mario, everything is pretty much blocks. A good implementation should only check for necessary collision, for instance, if Mario is running and at the end of the way, there is a cliff, how should we check for collision efficiently? Should we always check on every step Mario is taking to see whether his hitbox is still on the ground? Or is there some other programming way that allows us to not handle this every frame?

But blocks are boring, let's put in some slopes. Implementation details-wise, how should slopes be handled? Some games such as Sonic, have this loop structure that the character can go "woohoo" in the loop and proceed.

Another scenario is "solid" objects (floor, ceiling, wall) handling. [In Megaman, we can see that the player can make himself go through the ceiling by using a tool to go into the solid "wall".](http://tasvideos.org/GameResources/NES/Rockman.html#EnteringCeilingsAndWalls) Possibly, the programming here is to force the player to go out of the wall so that the player is not stuck, by moving the player quickly to the right. This is an old "workaround" method to avoid player stucking in wall. In newer games these days, the handle is more complex. Take, for instance, Super Smash Brawl, where players can enlarge the characters (along with their hitbox) The program allows the player to move around "in" the ceiling, but once the character is out of the "solid" area, they cannot move back in. Moreover, sometimes, a character is gigantic that they go through 3 solid floors of a scene  and they can still move inside fine. Anybody knows implementation details along these lines?

So here, I know that there are many implementation possible, but I just wanna ask here that are there some advanced technical details for platformer game that I should be aware of? I am currently asking for 3 things:

1. How should solid collision of platformer game be handled efficiently? Can we take lesser time to check whether a character has ran and completely fell off a platform?
2. Slope programming. At first, I was thinking of physics engine, but I think it might be overkill. But in here, I see that slopes are pretty much another types of floor that "push" or "pull" the character to different elevation. Or should it be programmed differently?
3. Solid objects handling for special cases. There might be a time where the player can slip into the solid objects either via legal game rules or glitches, but all in all, it is always a bad idea to push the player to some random direction if he is in a wall.

Comment: Good question, but it might be a good idea to split it into multiple questions. I am interested in the answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. For a small number of objects, doing an all-pairs collision detection check at each time step is fine. Once you get more than a couple hundred objects, you may want to start considering a more efficient method. One way is to use a [binary space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) (BSP) to only check against nearby objects. Collision detection is a very well researched topics and there are a plethora of resources describing various optimizations.
2. Indeed, a physics engine is likely overkill for this task. Generally speaking, you can associate with each moving character a "ground" on which he is standing. Then whenever he moves, you simply make him move along the axis of the ground.
3. Slipping into objects is almost always a bad idea. Try to avoid it if possible.